# return json structure using perl

Tags: json, perl

i have the following sql statement inside a function..

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq[SELECT device_uuid,device_name FROM ].DB_SCHEMA().qq[.user_device WHERE user_id = ?]);
 $sth->execute($user_id) || die $dbh->errstr;
```

the results are being fetched using the following statement

```
 while(my $data = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {

}
```

my question is how can i create and return a json structure containing objects for every row being fetched?something like this

```
{
 object1:{
   "device_uuid1":"id1",
   "device_name1":"name1"
    },
 object2:{
   "device_uuid2":"id2",
   "device_name2":"name2"
    },
 object3:{
   "device_uuid3":"id3",
   "device_name3":"name3"
    }
}
```

the total number of json objects will be equal to the number of rows returned by the sql statement.
i have managed to build the structure like this

```
$VAR1 = [{"device_name":"device1","device_id":"device_id1"},{"device_name":"device2","device_id":"device_id2"}]
```

how can i iterate through  the array refs and get "device_name" and "device_id" values?

Comment: Look at the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module.

Comment: FYI you properly want to output: `[{...},{...},{...}]` <-- an array with objects (hashes)

Comment: dev-null  how can i  iterate through the structure you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, [this](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#encode) library should work well. What you need to do is have a scalar variable defined as below and push the element for each iteration in while loop

```
my $json = JSON->new->utf8->space_after->encode({})

while(my $data = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
    #Push new element here in $json using incr_parse method
    #or using $json_text = $json->encode($perl_scalar)
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you explain in more detail what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

finally what i did was to create an array ref and push the fetched rows which are being returned as hash refs

```
my @device = ();
while(my $data = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        push(@device, $data);
}
```

last i convert the @device array ref to json and return the outcome

```
return encode_json(\@device);
```

Comment: Why call `fetchrow_hashref()` multiple times, when `fetchall_arrayref()` will do what you want in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

The statement handle method `fetchall_arrayref()` can return an array reference where each element in the referenced array is a hash reference containing details of one row in the resultset. This seems to me to be exactly the data structure that you want. So you can just call that method and pass the returned data structure to a JSON encoding function.

```
# Passing a hash ref to fetchall_arrayref() tells it to
# return each row as a hash reference.
my $json = encode_json($sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample JSON is incorrect - JSON is actually quite nicely represented by perl data structures - `[]` denotes array, `{}` denotes key-value (very similar to hash).

I would rather strongly suggest though, that what you've asked for is probably not what you want - you've seemingly gone for globally unique keys, which ... isn't good style when they're nested.

Why? well, so you can do things like this:

```
print $my_data{$_}->{'name'} for keys %my_data;
```

Far better to go for something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use JSON;

my %my_data = (
        object1 => {
            uuid => "id1",
            name => "name1"
        },
        object2 => {
            uuid => "id2",
            name => "name2"
        },
        object3 => {
            uuid => "id3",
            name => "name3"
        },
 );

print Dumper \%my_data;
print to_json ( \%my_data, { 'pretty' => 1 } )."\n";
```

Now, that does assume your 'object1' is a unique key - if it isn't, you can instead do something like this - an array of anonymous hashes (for bonus points, it preserves ordering)

```
my @my_data = (
    {   object1 => {
            uuid => "id1",
            name => "name1"
        }
    },
    {   object2 => {
            uuid => "id2",
            name => "name2"
        }
    },
    {   object3 => {
            uuid => "id3",
            name => "name3"
        }
    },
);
```

Now, how to take your example and extend it? Easy peasy really - assemble what you want to add to your structure in your loop, and insert it into the structure:

```
while(my $data = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
     my $objectname = $data -> [0]; #assuming it's this element!
     my $uuid = $data -> [1];
     my $name = $data -> [2]; 
     my $new_hash = { uuid => $uuid, name => $name }; 
     $mydata{$objectname} = $new_hash; 
}
```